# Is there are a simple tool to organize photo based on date?

Tags: photos, file, macos, exif

I have lots of photos and most of them are in unordered folders.

Is there a simple tool (no batch script) which can just read those images and based on EXIF date put them in a date based folder?

Something like: /year/month/day/foto_1.jpg

The only things I can find so far are bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Found a free tool which does it all:

[exifrenamer](https://www.qdev.de/?location=mac/exifrenamer)

Comment: That tool turned out not to work too good. So I finally created my own batch file which uses this tool under the hood:  https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Just using the perl tool alone, didn't do it for me.